# How does Scons compute the build signature?

Tags: scons

I keep different versions of one project in different directories. (This *does* make sense in this project. Sadly.) As there are only minor differences between the versions, I hope I can speed all builds after the first one by using a common cache directory for all builds.

Unfortunately I had to realise that, when building an object file from the same sources in different directories, SCons 2.3.3 stores the result on different locations in the cache. (The location is equal to the build signature, I assume.) The same sources are recompiled for each and every directory. So why does SCons determine different build signatures although

- the compile commands are identical and
- the sources and the include files are the same (identical output of of the preprocessor phase, `gcc -E ...`)
- I'm using the decider "MD5-timestamp"

Even the resulting object files are identical!

For a trivial example (`helloworld` from the SCons documentation) re-using the cache works. Though in the big project I'm working on, it does not. Maybe the "SCons build environment" influences the build signature, even if it does not have any effect on the compile command?

Are there any debug options that could help besides `--cache-debug=-`? Which method of SCons determines the build signature?

The folders look somewhat like this:

```
<basedir1>/
       SConstruct
       src/something.cpp …
       include/header.hpp …
<basedir2>/
       SConstruct
       src/something.cpp …
       include/header.hpp …
/SharedCache/
       0/ 1/ 2/ … F/
```

I check out the project in both *basedir1* and *basedir2* and call `scons --build-cache-dir=/SharedCache` in both of them. (EDIT: `--build-cache-dir` is a custom option, implemented in the `SConstruct` file of this project. It maps to `env.CacheDir('/SharedCache')`.

EDIT2: Before I realized this problem, I did some tests to evaluate the effects of using `--cache-implicit` or SCons 2.4.0.

Comment: Can you paste an example compile command line? Try --debug=explain also.  Likely you have some portion of the path in the command line which has more than the relative path in it. Thus the command line is different.   (I note you have an active question on the scons users mailing list for this issue as well)

Comment: I re-verified that the compile commands are identical. Every bit. Here's an abridget example: `g++ -o <target>.o -c -m64 -I<global_include_path> -fmessage-length=0 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE …  -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Werror -Wsign-promo … -DXOC_FILE_ID=\"ProtocolUnitTester:ate_ext_td_ProtocolFrameworkTests_generated.cpp\" -fPIC -Iinclude -Iinclude-uda -I. <src>.cpp`.

Comment: By "when building an object file from the same sources in different directories, SCons 2.3.3 stores the result on different locations in the cache." do you mean that the sources are in different directories under the SConstruct? Or do you mean that the directory structure under SConstruct is the same, but the base directory for the SConstruct is the only thing which differs?  so <basedir>/a/b/c/abc.c and <basedir>/a/b/d/abc.c or <basedir_a>/a/b/c/abc.c and <basedir_b>/a/b/c/abc.c where the SConstruct is in the basedir.

Comment: @bdbaddog It's <basedir_a>/a/b/c/abc.c  and <basedir_b>/a/b/c/abc.c.

Comment: A command-line parameter `--build-cache-dir` doesn't exist in SCons, neither in v2.3.5 nor in the latest trunk. When I specify the cache dir explicitly in each SConstruct, things work as expected. Based on the infos and examples you've given so far, I'm not able to reproduce the problem on my side...

Answer (score 1):

This is the code of the method `get_cachedir_bsig()` from the file `src/engine/SCons/Node/FS.py`:

```
def get_cachedir_bsig(self):
    """
    Return the signature for a cached file, including
    its children.

    It adds the path of the cached file to the cache signature,
    because multiple targets built by the same action will all
    have the same build signature, and we have to differentiate
    them somehow.
    """
    try:
        return self.cachesig
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    # Collect signatures for all children
    children = self.children()
    sigs = [n.get_cachedir_csig() for n in children]
    # Append this node's signature...
    sigs.append(self.get_contents_sig())
    # ...and it's path
    sigs.append(self.get_internal_path())
    # Merge this all into a single signature
    result = self.cachesig = SCons.Util.MD5collect(sigs)
    return result
```

It shows how the path of the cached file is included into the "cache build signature", which explains the behaviour you see. For the sake of completeness, here is also the code of the `get_cachedir_csig()` method from the same `FS.py` file:

```
def get_cachedir_csig(self):
    """
    Fetch a Node's content signature for purposes of computing
    another Node's cachesig.

    This is a wrapper around the normal get_csig() method that handles
    the somewhat obscure case of using CacheDir with the -n option.
    Any files that don't exist would normally be "built" by fetching
    them from the cache, but the normal get_csig() method will try
    to open up the local file, which doesn't exist because the -n
    option meant we didn't actually pull the file from cachedir.
    But since the file *does* actually exist in the cachedir, we
    can use its contents for the csig.
    """
    try:
        return self.cachedir_csig
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    cachedir, cachefile = self.get_build_env().get_CacheDir().cachepath(self)
    if not self.exists() and cachefile and os.path.exists(cachefile):
        self.cachedir_csig = SCons.Util.MD5filesignature(cachefile, \
            SCons.Node.FS.File.md5_chunksize * 1024)
    else:
        self.cachedir_csig = self.get_csig()
    return self.cachedir_csig
```

where the cache paths of the children are hashed into the final build signature.

**EDIT:** The "cache build signature" as computed above, is then used to build the "cache path". Like this, all files/targets can get mapped to a unique "cache path" by which they can get referenced and found in (= retrieved from) the cache. As the comments above explain, the relative path of each file (starting from the top-level folder of your SConstruct) is a part of this "cache path". So, if you have the same source/target (foo.c->foo.obj) in different directories, they will have different "cache paths" and get built independent of each other.

If you truly want to share sources between different projects, note how the CacheDir functionality is more intended for sharing the same sources between different developers, you may want to have a look at the Repository() method. It let's you mount (blend in) another source tree to your current project...

Comment: (A) If you were right in assuming that the _absolute_ path was part of the build signature, the cache would not work in my trivial `helloworld` example. Though the caching _does_ work in this case. (B) I removed the target file, started `scons --debug=pdb` and `break SCons.Node.FS.File.get_cachedir_bsig`. The debugger did _not_ stop in `get_cachedir_bsig`.

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding: You assume that there are two files with the same content in the project. My situation is: The project is checked out twice.

Comment: Possible. So can you please clarify in your question how you check out your sources twice, and then arrange it for SCons, which I assume is under control of both copies, that it doesn't see two copies but only one? How does your folder structure actually look like and how do you setup your SConstructs?